# Running tests on several objects

Tags: capybara

I have the following test:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('ul', count: 1)
expect(page).to have_selector('li', count: 21)
expect(page).to have_selector('li img', count: 21)
```

Basically I want to check that the list exists, that it has exactly 21 items and that each item has an image.

The problem with my code is that if the first element has 2 images, and the second has none, it would still pass.

How could I check every list item individually? Something like this...

```
expect(page).to have_selector('ul', count: 1)
expect(page).to have_selector('li', count: 21)
foreach('li') do |item|
    expect(item).to have_selector('img', count: 1)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Florent B. is correct and tests what you want.  To make the checks the way you were thinking you could do something like

```
expect(page).to have_selector('ul', count: 1)
lis = page.all('li', count: 21)  # same effect as expectation since it will raise an exception if not 21 on page but gets access to the elements
lis.each do |li|
  expect(li).to have_selector('img', count: 1)
end
```

however due to the number of queries that would perform the answer by Florent B. is going to be much quicker

Answer (score 1):

I would simply check with an XPath that there's no `li` where the image count is not 1:

```ruby
expect(page).to have_selector('ul', count: 1)
expect(page).to have_selector('ul li', count: 21)
expect(page).to have_selector('ul li img', count: 21)
expect(page).to have_no_xpath('//ul//li[count(.//img) != 1]')
```

Comment: There was no `has_no_xpath` available. There was a `has_no_xpath?`, but when I use it, I get an `The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to `#to`.`

Comment: @Dbugger it should be `have_no_xpath`